# SSRS : Percentage Target

Tags: reporting-services

I'm new at SSRS and I'd like to do a special chart
So I have some data, one is my sale target and the other one is my current status by stores
So I'd like to do a chart like a stacked column but not with the sum of values like it's the case but something similar to a gauge, I can do a gauge that I put in a table but I'd prefer to have everything on a similar chart like stacked column,

So I'd like a stacked chart with similar column:

[image: Here the idea]

I also like to be able to change the color of my column if  my current status exceed my target

Any idea of how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my design:

My data structure:

[image]

I insert a Chart(bar chart)

[image]

Then I click [amount]  series to configure it, you will get result like below(if you think the target column is overlapped by amount column, you could change target column to line type)

[image]

Zoe Zhi